# Error Forbbiden cuando quiero ejecutar con codeigniter no tengo permiso del servidor

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo un problrema, tengo mi carpeta proyecto en framework de codeigniter con programas ya trabajados luego pase mi carpeta de proyecto a otra computadora y quise ejecutar cada uno de los controladores y ademas vistas pero el servidor me muestra que no tengo permiso, luego instale otro framework codeigniter y ocurre lo mismo como vuelo a ejecutar mis programas en codeigniter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto esta ubicado en la carpeta "www" uso el paquete appserv (phpmyadmin, mysql apache)
mis configuraciones:

- proyecto/application/config:
- $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/20151/proyecto/';
- $config['index_page']='index.php';
- proyecto/application/routes
- $route['default_controller'] = "tienda";
- $route['404_override'] = '';
- proyecto/application/autoload:
- $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
- $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

en el archivo .htacces solo tiene esto escrito : deny from all

como puedo hacer para usar codeigniter en mi servidor apache

Comment: Hola buenas tarde por lo que puedo ver en tu url estas llamando desde la vista a tu página en el caso de codeigniter utiliza una estructura mvc por lo que tienes que llamar a la vista de la controladora. Si gustas coloca tu código de la controladora y la vista  y así te puedo ayudar mejor. El otro detalle que veo es que no estas pasando por el index.php los datos sino que los estas colocando directo.

Comment: @YoelRodriguez Deberias pasar ese comentario a una respuesta

Comment: @leonbloy en seguida lo voy hacer gracias por su recomendación.

Answer (score 0):

> en el archivo .htacces solo tiene esto escrito : deny from all

Seguramente este es el problema.

**deny from all**, impede cualquier acceso
por lo que posiblemente esto este bloqueando el acceso.

Puedes por ejemplo denegar todos menos X accesos:

```
Order deny, allow
Deny from All
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

O por el contrario permitir todos menos x

```
Order deny, allow
Allow from All
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Puedea añadir tantos rangos como necesites:

```
Order deny, allow
Allow from All
Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Deny from xxx.xxx.yyyy.yyy
Deny from xxx.zzz.zzz.zzz
```

o directamente borra el contenido y deja el archivo vacío.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que puedo ver en tu ***url*** estas llamando desde la vista a tu página. En el caso de ***codeigniter***, utiliza una estructura ***mvc***, por lo que tienes que llamar a la vista desde la controladora.

Otro detalle que veo, es que no estas pasando por el ***index.php*** los datos sino que los estas colocando directo.

> Nota: Si gustas coloca tu código de la controladora y la vista y así
>   te puedo ayudar mejor.